# CloudFormation YAML combining FN::GEtAtt and !Ref to list ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Was wrestling with the CloudFormation syntax of Generating VPCSecurityGroupIds (1 in my case).  I have the below yaml, basically attempting to reference the parameter SecurityGroupName inside the GetAtt function.  Unfortunatley I get the "Parameters [SecurityGroupName] must have values when I know I am passing in correct SecurityGroupName value.  Any insight to this nesting is greatly appreciated.

```
  Properties:
    VpcSecurityGroupIds:
      - "Fn::GetAtt": [ !Ref SecurityGroupName , "GroupId"]

  Translates to

  Properties:
    VpcSecurityGroupIds:
    - Fn:G:GetAtt:
      - Ref: SecurityGroupName
      - GroupId
```

Comment: Can you show the parameter in your question?

Comment: Can you say more about what you're trying to achieve? `!GetAtt` would generally only work for a resource in the same template where it's being used, so if `SecurityGroupName` is referencing a SG from somewhere else, `!GetAtt` wouldn't be able to lookup it's `GroupId`.

The common thing to do here would be to pass the group ID as the parameter, rather than the group name, if the ID is the required value. Or pass both, if they are both necessary.

Comment: In addition to Farski comment: ... or use export/import if it's from another stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can't do this**. Argument to `Fn::GetAtt` can't be any function. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html):

> For the Fn::GetAtt logical resource name, you **can't use functions**. You must specify a string that's a resource's logical ID.

Comment: Thanks for the above, missed this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Properties:
    VpcSecurityGroupIds:
       - Fn::GetAtt:
          - !Ref SecurityGroupName
          - GroupId
```

I have it working in several places. Also include resource Type in sample, will be much easier to find what you talk about.

also to make sure sure you do pass `SecurityGroupName` value, add it to Parameters with set default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have the below yet I get a "Template error:  if specifying one argument to Fn::GetAtt, that argument must be a non-empty string in format <LogicalId>.<Attribute>.  I defaulted the parameter just to be certain.

  SecurityGroupName:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Security group Name
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '100'
    Default: "test"
Resources:
  RDSCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBCluster'
    Properties:
      VpcSecurityGroupIds: 
        - Fn::GetAtt:
          - !Ref SecurityGroupName
          - GroupId

Comment: Do you have a defined lists of possible values for `SecurityGroupName` ? What's the source of it?