Cloudformation template with !Split !GetAtt and !Sub
I'm struggling to reference the string of subnet ids from my nested stack which is environment dependent. How does one use !Split, !GetAtt and !Sub?
LambdaSubnetsString looks something like this: 'subnetIdA,subnetIdB'
Here is what I tried:
MyFn:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
        VpcConfig:
            SubnetIds: !Split [
              ',',
               !GetAtt [NetworkingStack, Fn::Sub: 'Outputs.${environment}-LambdaSubnetsString']
            ]

Got error: "Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: the resource attribute in Fn::GetAtt must be of type string or a reference to a string typed parameter"
and
MyFn:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
        VpcConfig:
            SubnetIds: !Split [
              ',',
              !GetAtt
                  - NestedStack
                  - !Sub 'Outputs.${environment}-LambdaSubnetsString'
            ]

Got error: "Error: Failed to parse template: while parsing a flow sequence
in "", line 181, column 27:
SubnetIds: !Split [
^
expected ',' or ']', but got '-'
in "", line 184, column 13:
- NestedStack
^"

Resolved by passing the name as a string from the GitHub actions script but that's not the cleanest solution...
SubnetIds: !Split [',', !GetAtt [NetworkingStack, !Ref lambdaSubnetsStringName]]

where lambdaSubnetsStringName is set to Outputs.${environment}-LambdaSubnetsString

Was inspired from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978635/cloudformation-yaml-combining-fngetatt-and-ref-to-list-ids

i tested your scenario and got this as one of the solution:
networking-template.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: >
  Environment-dependent template to create a basic VPC with subnets for Lambda function testing.

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: The environment name (e.g., dev, test, prod)

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${Environment}-VPC"

  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: 
        Fn::Select: 
          - 0
          - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${Environment}-SubnetA"

  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: 
        Fn::Select: 
          - 1
          - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${Environment}-SubnetB"

Outputs:
  VPCId:
    Description: The ID of the VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${Environment}-VPCId"

  LambdaSubnetsString:
    Description: Comma-separated list of subnet IDs for Lambda
    Value: !Join [",", [!Ref SubnetA, !Ref SubnetB]]
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${Environment}-LambdaSubnetsString"


main-template.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: >
  CloudFormation template to deploy a Lambda function with VPC configuration.

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: The environment name (e.g., dev, test, prod)

Resources:
  MyLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: LambdaBasicExecution
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*

  LambdaSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for Lambda function
      VpcId: !ImportValue 
        Fn::Sub: "${Environment}-VPCId" 

  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaRole.Arn
      Code: 
        ZipFile: |
          exports.handler = async (event) => {
              console.log("Hello from Lambda");
              return event;
          };
      VpcConfig:
        SubnetIds: !Split
          - ','
          - !ImportValue 
            Fn::Sub: "${Environment}-LambdaSubnetsString"
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 5

Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionArn:
    Description: ARN of the created Lambda function
    Value: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn

This way you can refernace subnet ids from nested stack whiche depends on environment.
